# Is there a compiler directive to replace part of a constant

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compiler-directives, preprocessor-directive

I'm working with embedded C for a microcontroller right now and I find that sometimes there are several peripherals that differ only by a single letter (for example UARTA, UARTB, etc).  The code for each peripheral is often times identical except for lettering of otherwise identical registers.  For example to setup peripheral A I would do something like:

```
UCA2CTL1 |= UCSWRST;                      // Put state machine in reset
UCA2CTL0 |= UCSYNC+UCCKPL+UCMSB;          // 3-pin, 8-bit SPI slave
// Continue initializing peripheral registers with "A" in name
```

And to setup peripheral B I have exactly the same code, except that the register names are transposed by 1 letter:

```
UCB2CTL1 |= UCSWRST;                      // Put state machine in reset
UCB2CTL0 |= UCSYNC+UCCKPL+UCMSB;          // 3-pin, 8-bit SPI slave
// Continue initializing peripheral registers with "B" in name
```

I would like to have the ability to change which peripheral I target without having to #ifdef/copy/paste code or find/replace.  Is there some compiler directive or clever trick that can implement this behavior so that I only have to write the code once? I would love to just #define the last letter in the peripheral, but something like that seems to wander dangerously close to code stink to me.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use a macro or two here?

Comment: @thelazydeveloper - I'd love to, that's what I'm asking for here.

Comment: You are actually better off NOT doing this.  Consider "grep UCB2CTL1 *" to see why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
#define INITUC(device) \
UC ## device ## 2CTL1 |= UCSWRST; \
UC ## device ## 2CTL0 |= UCSYNC+UCCKPL+UCMSB
...
INITUC(A);
INITUC(B);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those constants are `const` and not `defines` You can do something like that:

```
#define MAKECONST(X) const int X ## 1; \
                     const int X ## 0; \
                     X ## 1 |= UCSWRST; \
                     X ## 0 |= UCSYNC+UCCKPL+UCMSB;
```

And then:

```
MAKECONST(UCA2CTL)
MAKECONST(UCB2CTL)
```

Note that my example includes declaration, which I don't know if you need, if not, omit first two lines of the define. E.g.:

```
#define SETUP(X) X ## 1 |= UCSWRST; \
                 X ## 0 |= UCSYNC+UCCKPL+UCMSB;
```